# Amazon Redshift - How to extract previous month data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to automate a report that runs at the beginning of each month to query out all sales for the previous month. Given below is the query I am using but it returns null value. Could anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here.

I am using Amazon Redshift

```
select created_at,sale_id from billing 
where to_char(created_at,'yyyy-mm') = EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE - '1 month'::interval);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing a string like `'2018-05'` to a numeric value like `5` (extract returns a single number) so that is not going to work. You need to use the same values on both sides of the equal sign, e.g.

```
select created_at,sale_id 
from billing 
where to_char(created_at,'yyyy-mm') = to_char(CURRENT_DATE - '1 month'::interval, 'yyyy-mm');
```